# isDirectory() returns true for a file

Tags: java, file, directory, java-io

In my java program I copy a file and delete the new file.

In my method `removeFile()` I check if it is a directory:

```
String fileName = "G:/1310628353186Examples.csv";
File f = new File(fileName);
if (f.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println( "'" + fileName + "' is a directory" );
    String[] files = f.list();
    if (files != null && files.length > 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: directory not empty: " + fileName);
}
```

Sometimes I get `"'G:/1310628353186Examples.csv' is a directory"`, sometimes I don't.

When I debug the code and `f.isDirectory()` is `true` and I check what is in `f.isDirectory`, the debugger says that it's `false`.

I'm running Eclipse SDK 3.4.0 and JDK 1.6 on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: What is `fileName`? Use `System.out.println( "'" + f + "' is a directory" );` to check what is in `f`!

Comment: You say that `f.isDirectory()` is evalutated to true, but the debugger says it is false? This can't be true ;)

Comment: I know :D

I start the debugger... It jumps into the code of isDirectory()... But if i check isDirectory() with watch it says false... And f.list() is null.

Comment: maybe it's worth trying `isFile()` instead of `isDirectory()`

Comment: same problem... sometimes it's true... sometimes it's false. either  isFile() is true or isDirectory()

Comment: hmm last thing i can think of: What filesystem is on G: ? Does this behavior also occur with other files on that drive (and maybe on for the same file on another drive like C:)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem caused by Windows. Linux does not have this problem.

Answer (score 8):

You check if `f` is a directory but you print `fileName`. So maybe you just check/print the wrong variable? Unless it's only a typo in your question.

Comment: Good catch! I stared at that code block for a good 3 minutes and got nothing :)

Comment: i forgot the first lines. sorry:/

Comment: Then you should follow Carlos' hint and print `f` instead of `fileName` (and some of its properties, like `getPath()` or `getAbsolutePath()` or `getName()`.

Comment: System.out.println("f: "+f);
      System.out.println("f.getPath(): "+f.getPath());
      System.out.println("f.getAbsolutePath(): "+f.getAbsolutePath());
      System.out.println("f.getName(): "+f.getName());

f: G:\1310631051940Example.csv
f.getPath(): G:\1310631051940Example.csv
f.getAbsolutePath(): G:\1310631051940Example.csv
f.getName(): 1310631051940Beispiele.csv
'G:\1310631051940Example.csv' is a directory

Comment: `f.getName(): 1310631051940Beispiele.csv` I assume you forgot to translate this one ;)

But I have no idea why `isDirectory()` would return true...

Comment: oh. yeah:/ should have been Example, too

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a check to see if the file exists, `isDirectory()` will also return false in case the file doesn't exist:

```
if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file is hidden, like the *My Music* link in *Documents* (a windows-generated shortcut file, it's not a real shortcut), then it will test as isdirectory but it won't function like a directory; you can't get a listing of the directory. A user generated shortcut will act like a file.

5/31/13:
In a recent update the 'My Music' link in 'Documents' no longer tests as is_hidden. However, a dirlist taken of the file object for 'My Music' does return a NULL, which can be tested for.

Answer (score 2):

I get this same issue on OSX. I create a regular file, and the `isDirectory()` function returns `true` and `isFile()` returns `false`. (Can't find any evidence anywhere to suggest that this behaviour is expected from the API).

The way I solved it on OSX is to manually read the attributes from the file, but you can't use `BasicFileAttributes` either - it also for some reason returns `true` for `isDirectory()` and `false` for `isRegularFile()`.

Works for OSX:

```
PosixFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(f.toPath(), PosixFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("File "+f.getName()+
                   ": isDirectory="+(attr.isDirectory() ? "true" : "false")+
                   ", isRegularFile="+(attr.isRegularFile() ? "true" : "false"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sorround with try/catch block and then try it.

Comment: At first, I only used
if (files.length > 0) 

... So I sometimes got a Null Pointer Exception.

With
if (files != null && files.length > 0)
no more exceptions are thrown.