# ProcessBuilder vs Runtime.getRuntime().exec different behavior

Tags: java, io

Given the code:

```
public String execCommand(String command, File folder) { 

        if (folder.isDirectory() && Files.isDirectory(folder.toPath())) {
            logger.info("It is a directory!"); //yes, is a directory!
        }

        try {

            Process runtimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, folder);       

            Process builderProc = new ProcessBuilder(command)
                    .directory(folder)
                    .redirectErrorStream(true)
                    .start();

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e, e::getMessage);
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

when I run the code it will execute the `runtimeProc` without problems, but the `builderProc` will throw an IOException:

> Cannot run program "myexecutable" (in directory
>   "/home/testing/1acbcd01-76d2-4981-8fd3-b863d6f9ede8"): error=20, Not a
>   directory: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "myexecutable action" (in
>   directory "/home/testing/1acbcd01-76d2-4981-8fd3-b863d6f9ede8"):
>   error=20, Not a directory

After reading through the code, I noticed that internally `Runtime.exec()` uses the `ProcessBuilder` class. How is this possible that one is working while the other is throwing an exception? and more importantly: How to fix it?

When debugging the "explosion point" is internally in jdk's `ProcessBuilder` class:

```
try {
            return ProcessImpl.start(cmdarray,
                                     environment,
                                     dir,
                                     redirects,
                                     redirectErrorStream);
        } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            String exceptionInfo = ": " + e.getMessage();
            Throwable cause = e;
            if ((e instanceof IOException) && security != null) {
                // Can not disclose the fail reason for read-protected files.
                try {
                    security.checkRead(prog);
                } catch (SecurityException se) {
                    exceptionInfo = "";
                    cause = se;
                }
            }
            // It's much easier for us to create a high-quality error
            // message than the low-level C code which found the problem.
            throw new IOException(
                "Cannot run program \"" + prog + "\""
                + (dir == null ? "" : " (in directory \"" + dir + "\")")
                + exceptionInfo,
                cause);
        }
```

Full StackTrace:

```
20:45:39,578 SEVERE [com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.control.Executor] (default task-32) Cannot run program "buildr run" (in directory "/home/wildfly/656a5d23-6457-4ee8-b2d8-d5b679c0a654"): error=20, Not a directory: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "buildr run" (in directory "/home/wildfly/656a5d23-6457-4ee8-b2d8-d5b679c0a654"): error=20, Not a directory                                                                                                                                                                
app_1   |       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.control.Executor.execCommand(Executor.java:38)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.boundary.buildtool.BuildTool.runClass(BuildTool.java:91)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.boundary.buildtool.BuildTool.runCode(BuildTool.java:49)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.boundary.WorkspaceProcessor.runCode(WorkspaceProcessor.java:62)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
app_1   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:70)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:80)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.tracing.TimeLogger.logTime(TimeLogger.java:19)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
app_1   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:89)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:329)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
app_1   |       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.boundary.WorkspaceProcessor$$$view47.runCode(Unknown Source)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
app_1   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.boundary.WorkspaceProcessor$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.runCode(Unknown Source)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.boundary.rest.WorkspaceProcessorResource.runCode(WorkspaceProcessorResource.java:44)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
app_1   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
app_1   |       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
app_1   |       at com.smorales.javalab.workspaceprocessor.boundary.rest.WorkspaceProcessorResource$$$view48.runCode(Unknown Source)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
app_1   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
app_1   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
app_1   |       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
app_1   |       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
app_1   |       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
app_1   |       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
app_1   |       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
app_1   |       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
app_1   |       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
app_1   |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
app_1   | Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=20, Not a directory
app_1   |       at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
app_1   |       at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
app_1   |       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
app_1   |       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
app_1   |       ... 189 more
```

Comment: As exception message tells you, `/home/testing/1acbcd01-76d2-4981-8fd3-b863d6f9ede8` is not a directory. Make sure that '/home/testing/1acbcd01-76d2-4981-8fd3-b863d6f9ede8' exists in the file system and it's a directory, not a file.

Comment: When debugging it enters in the `if` statement and the logger prints correctly.

Comment: You can also debug the `exec` method and find the point where exception is thrown. BTW, can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: added explosion point + stacktrace

Comment: I see, thanks. Just found another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689941/isdirectory-returns-true-for-a-file. Try to use `Files.isDirectory()` to check whether your dictory exists. Have you checked in manually in the file system? Is it a real directory? Not soft link?

Comment: Just checked it with `execCommand("notepad.exe", new File("C:\\Windows\\system32"));` on my Windows machine, worked like a charm. So looks like the problem comes from some platform specific features. Cause exception is thrown from method  `java.lang.ProcessImpl.start()`, it's documented as `// System-dependent portion of ProcessBuilder.start()`

Comment: well probably is a bug in the implementation. The funny thing is that `runtime.exec()` delegates to `ProcessBuilder` in the execution at some point, I expected both to fail.

Comment: thank you for your help, I found the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the difference:

By default `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` will tokenize the input, in the case of `ProcessBuilder` it will execute the command as it is (i.e: won't tokenize)

This is why the `Runtime` version can work properly, it will separate the command as:
`["buildr", "run"]` and in the other hand `ProcessBuilder` will run as: `["buildr run"]`.

The solution: Tokenize before using `ProcessBuilder` e.g:

```
String[] cmdAsTokens = command.split(" ");
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmdAsTokens)
                .directory(folder)
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .start();
```

Comment: Yes, `Runtime.exec()` uses `StringTokenizer` internally before delegating to `ProcessBuilder`.